# I'm trying to join two tables with multiple column

Tags: sql, database, join

My first table like:

```
ID; sip1; sip2; sip3; sip4;

01 ;  A1 ; A2   

02 ; B1 ; B2;  B3 ;   B4;

03 ; C1  ;C2 ; C3;
```

Second Table like,

```
SipX ; V1

A1   ; a

A2   ; b

B3   ; c

C2   ; d
```

How am I to join these two tables?
**I tried this:**

```
select * from firts_table a 
inner join second _table b on a.sip1 = b.sipx 
inner join second_table c on a.sip2 = c.sipx
inner join second_table d on a.sip3 = d.sipx
inner join second_table e on a.sip2 = e.sipx
```

It didnt work.
I expect to show:

```
ID; Sipx ; V1

01; A1 ; a
01; A2 ; b
02; B3 ; c
03; C2 ; d
```

*

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and what is your expected result.

Comment: select * from firts_table a
inner join second _table  b on a.sip1 = b.sipx
inner join second_table c  on a.sip2 = c.sipx

Comment: Please [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47772254/edit) your post explaining what you have tried, what is the result of your current query and what is your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    table_one.ID,
    table_two.*
FROM
   table_one
INNER JOIN
   table_two
       ON  table_two.SipX IN (table_one.sip1, table_one.sip2, table_one.sip3, table_one.sip4)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
   IF OBJECT_ID ('firsttable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE firsttable
GO

CREATE TABLE firsttable
    (
    id   INT NULL,
    sip1 VARCHAR (20) NULL,
    sip2 VARCHAR (20) NULL,
    sip3 VARCHAR (20) NULL,
    sip4 VARCHAR (20) NULL
    )
GO

IF OBJECT_ID ('secondtable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE secondtable
GO

CREATE TABLE secondtable
    (
    sipx VARCHAR (20) NULL,
    v1   VARCHAR (20) NULL
    )
GO



    select a.id,a.sip1 AS SIP1,b.v1 AS SIP1_V1,
                a.sip2 AS SIP2,c.v1 AS SIP2_V1,
                a.sip3 AS SIP3,d.v1 AS SIP3_V1,
                a.sip4 AS SIP4,e.v1 AS SIP4_V1
                 from firsttable a 
LEFT OUTER join secondtable b on a.sip1 = b.sipx 
LEFT OUTER join secondtable c on a.sip2 = c.sipx
LEFT OUTER join secondtable d on a.sip3 = d.sipx
LEFT OUTER join secondtable e on a.sip2 = e.sipx
```